# Django:- Real-time Name Display Issue: 'Account Not Found' Despite Existing Account Number

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-views

There is a `name` field in the `CustomUser` model that I want to display when a user inputs an account number in the `Transfer` model. What this means is validation: Imagine you want to transfer funds to someone's account. When the sender inputs the receiver's account number, I want the `name` field from the `CustomUser` model to be displayed in the `name` field of the `Transfer` model in real-time, to accomplish this, I need to query the `Account` model and send the results to a `JsonResponse`, But I don't understand why it says `Account Not Found` even though the account number does exist in the database.

**Models.py**

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_number = models.IntegerField()
    account_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6, default=0.0)
    account_status = models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=ACCOUNT_STATUS)
    is_accepted_for_Loan = models.BooleanField()
```

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    account_number = models.IntegerField()
    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender_user')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver_user')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6, default=0.0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Template**

```
<input type="number" id="account_number" placeholder="Receiver's Account Number">
<p>Receiver Name: <span id="receiver_name"></span></p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#account_number').on('input', function() {
            let url = "{% url 'Get_Receiver_Infor' %};
            var accountNumber = $(this).val();
            if (accountNumber.length > 9) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#receiver_name').text(data.name);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $( '#receiver_name').text('Account Not Found');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#receiver_name').text('Something Went Wrong Please Try Again');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Views**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def get_receiver_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        receiver_account_number = request.POST.get('account_number')

        try:
            receiver_account = Account.objects.get(account_number=receiver_account_number)
            receiver_user = receiver_account.user

            response_data = {
                'name': receiver_user.name,
            }

            return JsonResponse(response_data)
        except Account.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Account not found'}, status=404)
    return render (request, 'Profile/transfer.html')
```

Comment: Your `$.ajax` does not contain any data, hence `request.POST.get('account_number')` will be `None`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  When I input the account_number in the acount_number input, it says: `Account Not Found` In real-time.

Comment: because you never pass it to the view to start with, this is one of the (many) reasons not to use `request.POST.get` either, since it returns `None` if the key is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass the account number as data, hence the error:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#account_number').on('input', function() {
            let url = "{% url 'Get_Receiver_Infor' %}";
            var accountNumber = $(this).val();
            if (accountNumber.length > 9) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {account_number: accountNumber},
                    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#receiver_name').text(data.name);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $( '#receiver_name').text('Account Not Found');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#receiver_name').text('Something Went Wrong Please Try Again');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

> **Note**: Please use `request.POST['account_number']` over `request.POST.get('account_number')`. Using `.get(…)` often only silences the error, but not the problem: indeed it will work if the key is missing. But if the value for that key is really required, it will only result in more trouble later in the process.

Comment: After changing what you have recommend, is still return that error when I inputs the Account number.

Comment: @AdamuDeeAzare: so you added `data: {account_number: accountNumber},`?

Comment: Yes, and changing `request.POST.get()` to `request.POST[]`

Comment: @AdamuDeeAzare: are you sure it is not the XSRF token? Since you don't see the response data in the `error`, it is hard to know. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax

Comment: Now there is something I have seen in the browser console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with get_receiver_infor/:1 a status of 403(forbidden)`

Comment: AdamuDeeAzare: well then it is likely it is the CSRF-token, you should collect the token from the cookie (as described in the link) and add it to the request header.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but is still showing the error message, and the error message on my CMD: `Forbidden (CSRF Token from the 'X-Csrftoken' HTTP  header has incorrect length.): /get_receiver_infor/`.

Comment: The `Account Not Found` is still showing in the transfer template.